# CSV module Python

Tags: python, csv

I've a large CSV files (about a million records). I want to process write each record into a DB.

Since loading the complete file into the RAM makes no sense, hence I need to read the file in chunks (or any other better way).

So, I wrote this code .

```
import csv
with open ('/home/praful/Desktop/a.csv') as csvfile:
    config_file = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',', quotechar = '|')
    print config_file
    for row in config_file:
        print row
```

I guess it loads everything into its memory first and then process.

Upon looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444679/reading-a-huge-csv-in-python) thread and many others, I didnt see any difference in o/p code and the solution. Kindly advise, is it the only method for efficient processing of csv files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `csv` module produces an *iterator*; rows are produced on demand. Unless you keep references to `row` elsewhere the file will *not* be loaded into memory in its entirety.

Note that that is exactly what I am saying in the other answer you linked to; the problem there is that the OP was building a list (`data`) holding all rows after reading instead of processing the rows as they were being read.