# Writing csv reader to excel using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, win32com

I want to write the csv (huge) data to excel file using python.
I have read the csv file using csv.reader like-

```
with open(main_path+i_bu_name+"/"+str(snapshot_id)+"/"+input_folder+input_csv_name,'rb') as input:
                print "entering file read"
                reader=csv.reader(input)
                #datalist=list(reader)
```

Now i want to paste this reader to an existing excel file which has some formatting saved in it so i am using win32com python library to write csv reader data to excel.
Whenever i try pandas to_excel() method, it removes the existing formatting from excel. 
Please help, how can i write this huge data to excel without removing formatting from excel.

Comment: Can you please add your Excel-related code and a stack trace? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a huge .csv in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444679/reading-a-huge-csv-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Value property:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A5").Value = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: I am using Value property, but as i said my data is huge so there is always memory problem.

Comment: Please, add example code and error you get to the question.

Comment: IMHO, fragmenting the data [e.g. based on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444679/reading-a-huge-csv-in-python) and populating the excel file with the fragments' contents would do the trick.

Comment: reading the data was not the problem statement, problem is in writing it to xls file.