# How to read data in Python dataframe without concatenating?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, chunks

I want to read the file f (file size:85GB) in chunks to a dataframe. Following code is suggested.

```
chunksize = 5
TextFileReader = pd.read_csv(f, chunksize=chunksize)
```

However, this code gives me TextFileReader, not dataframe. Also, I don't want to concatenate these chunks to convert TextFileReader to dataframe because of the memory limit. Please advise.

Comment: Sorry what are you asking here? you can't load the entire dataframe into memory which is why you read in chunks so why do you think that concatenating all the chunks will solve this problem?

Comment: Storing them in a list !?? I do not get what you want actually to achieve. Do you want to have the chunks separately?
Please be aware that your `TextFileReader` is an iterable object where you can retrieve the individual chunks via `for chunk in TextFileReader`

Comment: You can use for loop(chunksize), in each iteration you will get one dataframe for each chunk. Loop will run five times and you can merge all dataframes at the end.

Comment: So loop over `TextFileReader` as explained above and do with the chunks whatever you want (reduce them, group them, ...)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As you are trying to process 85GB CSV file, if you will try to read all the data by breaking it into chunks and converting it into dataframe then it will hit memory limit for sure. You can try to solve this problem by using different approach. In this case, you can use filtering operations on your data. For example, if there are 600 columns in your dataset and you are interested only in 50 columns. Try to read only 50 columns from the file. This way you will save lot of memory. Process your rows as you read them. If you need to filter the data first, use a generator function. `yield` makes a function a generator function, which means it won't do any work until you start looping over it.

For more information regarding generator function:
[Reading a huge .csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444679/reading-a-huge-csv-in-python)

For efficient filtering refer: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/88885/efficiently-filter-a-large-100gb-csv-file-v3

For processing smaller dataset:

**Approach 1: To convert reader object to dataframe directly:**

```
full_data = pd.concat(TextFileReader, ignore_index=True)
```

It is necessary to add parameter [ignore index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#ignoring-indexes-on-the-concatenation-axis) to function concat, because avoiding duplicity of indexes.

**Approach 2:** **Use Iterator or get_chunk to convert it into dataframe.**

By specifying a chunksize to read_csv,return value will be an iterable object of type TextFileReader.

```
df=TextFileReader.get_chunk(3)

for chunk in TextFileReader:
    print(chunk)
```

Source : http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking

`df= pd.DataFrame(TextFileReader.get_chunk(1))`

This will convert one chunk to dataframe.

**Checking total number of chunks in TextFileReader**

```py
for chunk_number, chunk in enumerate(TextFileReader):
    # some code here, if needed
    pass

print("Total number of chunks is", chunk_number+1)
```

If file size is bigger,I won't recommend second approach. For example, if csv file consist of 100000 records then chunksize=5 will create 20,000 chunks.

Comment: Ok, but the screenshot you shared says it will still give TextFileReader. So, how should I convert that to Dataframe?

Comment: try chunk_1= pd.DataFrame(TextFileReader.get_chunk(1)) This will convert one chunk to dataframe

Comment: My data has millions of rows. So, I can't use 2nd approach. And, 1st approach has concatenation. So, I will hit the memory limit thanks to my 85GB csv file. What should I do?

Comment: If you can convert your csv file to some compressed file format which is supported by Python. In that case it will be easy to read data.

Comment: Check accepted answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444679/reading-a-huge-csv-in-python

Answer (score 4):

If you want to receive a data frame as a result of working with chunks, you can do it this way. Initialize empty data frame before you initialize chunk iterations. After you did the filtering process you can concatenate every result into your dataframe. As a result you will receive a dataframe filtered by your condition under the for loop.

```
file = 'results.csv'
df_empty = pd.DataFrame()
with open(file) as fl:
    chunk_iter = pd.read_csv(fl, chunksize = 100000)
    for chunk in chunk_iter:
        chunk = chunk[chunk['column1'] > 180]
        df_empty = pd.concat([df_empty,chunk])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  full_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(TextFileReader.get_chunk(100000))
```