# Sum series in pandas dataframe in two ways

Tags: python, pandas, series

I am training on pandas and how to sum a series in a DataFrame. And I could use two ways using list and normal variable.
The code is like that

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'http://bit .ly/imdbratings'
df = pd.read_csv(url , chunksize=250)

result = []
for chunk in df:
    result.append(sum(chunk['duration']))
print(sum(result))
```

The code is working well and the output is 118439

And when using a variable instead of list like that

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'http://bit .ly/imdbratings'
df = pd.read_csv(url , chunksize=250)

total = 0
for chunk in df:
    total += sum(chunk['duration'])
print(total)
```

The output is the same 118439

** The problem is when trying the both approaches in one code like that

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'http://bit .ly/imdbratings'
df = pd.read_csv(url, chunksize=250)

result = []
for chunk in df:
    result.append(sum(chunk['duration']))
print(sum(result))

total = 0
for chunk in df:
    total += sum(chunk['duration'])
print(total)
```

I got the result for the first approach but got 0 for the `total` variable. Any ideas why I got 0 when combining the two approaches?

** Remove the space in the url.

Answer (score 1):

The chunk is changing while calling. In my opinion this is an unexpected behavior and it has to be investigated.

If you print a number for each iteration you can see that you do npt enter the seconde code block and that's why your `total`variable stays at zero.

Try to run:

```
url = 'http://bit .ly/imdbratings'
df = pd.read_csv(url, chunksize=250)
print('Test Chunk 1')
for i, chunk in enumerate(df):
    print(i)
    #print(chunk)
print('Test Chunk 2')
for i, chunk in enumerate(df):
    print(i)
    #print(chunk)

>>> Test Chunk 1
0
1
2
3
Test Chunk 2
```

**EDIT**

I found a solution how to read in the data and store it as a pandas DataFrame, thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39386458/how-to-read-data-in-python-dataframe-without-concatenating).

There is one line added to concatenate all the chunks. Than you don't have to loop over the chunks anymore.

```
url = 'http://bit .ly/imdbratings'
df = pd.read_csv(url, chunksize=250)
df = pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True) # added line here

total = df['duration'].sum()
print(total)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. What if I need to apply both approaches in one code? How can I workaround this? I could repeat this line `df = pd.read_csv(url, chunksize=250)` before the second approach and it works. But I welcome any more ideas.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I need to deal with chunks. I think the code now deals with the whole dataframe at once or am I wrong?

Comment: Yes. It is only one DataFrame, anymore. But each chunk has an index. This index helps you to work with each individual chunk. You can also try `pd.DataFrame(df.get_chunk(2))`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can't get this part `pd.DataFrame(df.get_chunk(2))`

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this is working well ..

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('http://bit .ly/imdbratings', chunksize=250)

result = []
total = 0

for chunk in df:
    print(sum(chunk['duration']), len(chunk['duration']))
    result.append(sum(chunk['duration']))
    total += sum(chunk['duration'])

print('-'*10)
print(sum(result))
print(total)
```