# Loading very large CSV dataset into Python and R, Pandas struggles

Tags: python, r, pandas, csv, data.table

I am loading a huge csv (18GB) into memory and noticing very large differences between R and Python. This is on an AWS ec2 [r4.8xlarge which has 244 Gb of memory](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-next-generation-r4-memory-optimized-ec2-instances/). Obviously this is an extreme example, but the principle holds for smaller files on real machines too.

When using `pd.read_csv` my file took ~30 mins to load and took up 174Gb of memory. Essentially so much that I then can't do anything with it. By contrast, R's `fread()` from the `data.table` package took ~7 mins and only ~55Gb of memory.

Why does the pandas object take up so much more memory than the data.table object? Furthermore, why fundamentally is the pandas object almost 10x larger than the text file on disk? It's not like .csv is a particularly efficient way to store data in the first place.

Comment: Similar to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444679/reading-a-huge-csv-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444679/reading-a-huge-csv-file)

Comment: @RobertMc not in terms of pandas

Comment: Are you using 1.10.5 of `fread` which is new, in dev, and not yet on CRAN?  Try also [paratext](https://github.com/wiseio/paratext).

Comment: @MattDowle in which case are you suggesting that `fread` is reading incorrectly? The question is about why Python/Pandas doesn't mirror memory usage of `fread`.

Comment: @roganjosh  `fread` is much faster in dev (i.e. 1.10.5) which is why I'm asking.  No I'm not suggesting it is reading incorrectly.  The OP is also asking about speed as well as memory usage.

Comment: with that much data, why not convert it to an `hdf` file?

Comment: @djk47463 maybe that's what they are trying to do

Comment: @MattDowle, you could do that on chunks from any computer, there trying to just load in all the data for analysis I beleive

Comment: That’s right, I’m trying to load it into memory to run an sklearn model on it. The database I’m getting it from outputs this huge .tsv which is why I have this issue. You’re right that converting it to another format (hdf, parquet, feather, etc) is probably best, I just wanted to keep the pipeline as simple as possible. Sidenote: reading it to R with data.table, writing it to feather, then reading the feather into Python took ~12 mins total, compared to ~30 mins just using pd.read_csv straight to Python. That’s crazy to me.

Comment: was there ever an answer why pandas in 2019 still lags R's `fread` for speed?  I see the answer below for memory, but no answer for speed.  R's `fread` is so fast, it can often render converting to a binary format (feather, parquet) unnecessary.

Answer (score 15):

You won't be able to beat the speed of `fread`, but as far as memory usage goes my guess is that you have integers that are being read in as 64-bit integers in python.

Assuming your file looks like this:

```
a,b
1234567890123456789,12345
```

In R, you'll get:

```
sapply(fread('test.txt'), class)
#          a          b
#"integer64"  "integer"
```

Whereas in python (on a 64-bit machine):

```
pandas.read_csv('test.txt').dtypes
#a   int64
#b   int64
```

Thus you'll use more memory in python. You can force the type in `read_csv` as a workaround:

```
pandas.read_csv('test.txt', dtype={'b': numpy.int32}).dtypes
#a   int64
#b   int32
```

Small integers are also going to be the reason for both R and python objects taking up more space than the .csv file, since e.g. "1" in a .csv file takes up 2 bytes (char + either comma or end of line), but either 4 or 8 bytes in memory.

Comment: I think this is probably spot on. I never thought to use the `dtype` option in read_csv. Also, a lot my columns are just binary, but I bet it's treating all those 1's and 0's as big integers too. Is there an efficient numpy type for binary (or very small) integers or should I just use `int32`? Probably won't effect the speed, but it should definitely make it a lot smaller. Thanks.

Comment: You can try using `int8`.

Comment: I’ll try that. Any idea if there’s a way to say “this one column is int64, all the others are int8”? The documentation says you have to do it as a dict but I have several thousand columns (hence the large file size) so that seems a bit tedious.

Comment: I'd probably just read in the first couple of lines, create the dict based on the names, and then read the whole thing in.

Comment: Good call. That wouldn’t be hard at all. Thanks.