# simple While loop syntax error

Tags: python, while-loop, syntax

I've just begun experimenting Python for doing my thesis. I'd like to import a huge csv fileso I decided to import it by smaller parts, while skimming the significative data. The csv to import is 20GB and here is the function I came up with:

```
"""importing 10e6 rows at the time...with 10e7 rows python crashes"""
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def screma_dati(file):
    i=1000000
    print("\n...begin skimming...")

    #first reading
    data_values=pd.read_csv(file,nrows=i)
    print("\n\t Dataset:\t"+file)
    print("\n\t part n: 1")

    #further readings
    length_rows=i
    j=i
    while length_rows = i
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
        data=pd.read_csv(file,header=None,nrows=i,skiprow=j)
        shp=np.shape(data)
        length_rows=shp[0]
        idx=data.loc[data["mbaddr"].isin(np_cod)]#np_cod are reference code
        data_values.append(idx)
        j+=i
        print("\n\t part n: " +str(j/i))

    print("\n...end skimming...")

    return data_values
```

It gives me syntax error while compiling and even if it is probably a banal error I can't figure out how to solve it. 
I started with python just in these days so probably the function has few more errors..

PS[offtopic]: would this be a good way to import such a large dataset?

Comment: Missing colon on line with while loop. Need to have try before except. Need to indent code after except.

Comment: offtopic: you should try parsing your file line by line or chunk by chunk. Here's the general idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444679/reading-a-huge-csv-file

Comment: I added colon sign after while condition and still doesn't debug.

Comment: Can you double check for the correct whitespace (tabs vs spaces). You can use a view whitespace feature in a text editor or winword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while length_rows == i:
    pass
```

Also your except lacks "try"

```
 try: 
    something
 except Exception:
    something
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax error is after your while condition It should look like below. And you are using the **except** wrongly. You should be probably using **try** instead to except.

```
while length_rows = i:
    try:
        data=pd.read_csv(file,header=None,nrows=i,skiprow=j)
        shp=np.shape(data)
        length_rows=shp[0]
        idx=data.loc[data["mbaddr"].isin(np_cod)]#np_cod are reference code
        data_values.append(idx)
        j+=i
        print("\n\t part n: " +str(j/i))

    except KeyboardInterupt:
        raise   # or just simple pass 

print("\n...end skimming...")

return data_values
```

Hope this solves your problem...