# PySpark parquet datatypes

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I am using PySpark to read a relative large csv file (~10GB):

`ddf = spark.read.csv('directory/my_file.csv')`

All the columns have the datatype `string`

After changing the datatype of for example `column_a` I can see the datatype changed to an `integer`. If I write the `ddf` to a parquet file and read the parquet file I notice that all columns have the datatype `string` again. **Question:** How can I make sure the parquet file contains the correct datatypes so that I do not have to change the datatype again (while reading the parquet file).

**Notes**:

I write the `ddf` as a parquet file as follows:

`ddf.repartition(10).write.parquet('directory/my_parquet_file', mode='overwrite')`

I use:

- PySpark version `2.0.0.2`
- Python 3.x

Answer (score 0):

I read my large files with pandas and not have this problem. Try use pandas.
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

```
In[1]: Import pandas as pd

In[2]: df = pd.read_csv('directory/my_file.csv')
```

Comment: I have already used Pandas to read the file. However, due to the size of the data file and the calculations I have to do, I want to use PySpark to do the trick. Is there a way to read/write parquet files and 'save' the dtypes into the parquet file?

Comment: try use huge.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444679/reading-a-huge-csv-file