# How do I read a large csv file in Google Colab?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, google-colaboratory

So my csv file is stored in the local google colab directory. It is about 3.31 gb in size. When I run the following line of code:

```
truthdata = pd.read_csv("out.csv",header=0)
```

The session runs out of memory and reconnects. 
Please let me know how I can read this large csv file into a pandas dataframe. 
Thanks !!

Comment: You might try to process it in "chunks": like loading 10% in memory, doing some filtering, etc. loading the next chunk in memory, etc.

Comment: This SO post might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444679/reading-a-huge-csv-file. Specifically providing a solution using `pandas`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43286094/6143017

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem is there a way to do this on Colab ? Thanks.

Comment: @Adrian: thanks for the link, I might be able to work out a solution from it.

Answer (score 2):

The resources of google collab are limited to 12GB of RAM. Things you can do:

- Use `usecols` or `nrows` arguments in the `pd.read_csv`function to limit the number of columns and rows to read. That will decrease the memory
- Read the file by chunks and reduce the memory of each chunk using the following function. Afterwards `pd.concat` the chuncks

---

The code is not mine, I copied it from the following link and then tweaked it! https://www.mikulskibartosz.name/how-to-reduce-memory-usage-in-pandas/

```
def reduce_mem_usage(df, int_cast=True, obj_to_category=False, subset=None):
    """
    Iterate through all the columns of a dataframe and modify the data type to reduce memory usage.
    :param df: dataframe to reduce (pd.DataFrame)
    :param int_cast: indicate if columns should be tried to be casted to int (bool)
    :param obj_to_category: convert non-datetime related objects to category dtype (bool)
    :param subset: subset of columns to analyse (list)
    :return: dataset with the column dtypes adjusted (pd.DataFrame)
    """
    start_mem = df.memory_usage().sum() / 1024 ** 2;
    gc.collect()
    print('Memory usage of dataframe is {:.2f} MB'.format(start_mem))

    cols = subset if subset is not None else df.columns.tolist()

    for col in tqdm(cols):
        col_type = df[col].dtype

        if col_type != object and col_type.name != 'category' and 'datetime' not in col_type.name:
            c_min = df[col].min()
            c_max = df[col].max()

            # test if column can be converted to an integer
            treat_as_int = str(col_type)[:3] == 'int'
            if int_cast and not treat_as_int:
                treat_as_int = check_if_integer(df[col])

            if treat_as_int:
                if c_min > np.iinfo(np.int8).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.int8).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.int8)
                elif c_min > np.iinfo(np.uint8).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.uint8).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.uint8)
                elif c_min > np.iinfo(np.int16).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.int16).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.int16)
                elif c_min > np.iinfo(np.uint16).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.uint16).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.uint16)
                elif c_min > np.iinfo(np.int32).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.int32).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.int32)
                elif c_min > np.iinfo(np.uint32).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.uint32).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.uint32)
                elif c_min > np.iinfo(np.int64).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.int64).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.int64)
                elif c_min > np.iinfo(np.uint64).min and c_max < np.iinfo(np.uint64).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.uint64)
            else:
                if c_min > np.finfo(np.float16).min and c_max < np.finfo(np.float16).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.float16)
                elif c_min > np.finfo(np.float32).min and c_max < np.finfo(np.float32).max:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.float32)
                else:
                    df[col] = df[col].astype(np.float64)
        elif 'datetime' not in col_type.name and obj_to_category:
            df[col] = df[col].astype('category')
    gc.collect()
    end_mem = df.memory_usage().sum() / 1024 ** 2
    print('Memory usage after optimization is: {:.3f} MB'.format(end_mem))
    print('Decreased by {:.1f}%'.format(100 * (start_mem - end_mem) / start_mem))

    return df
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what exactly you want to do. In general [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) has a parameter called `chunksize` that allows you to iterate over chunks of the data. This is typically the approach to work with big files efficiently.

Comment: The csv file in question is a test data. I have a trained classfier and I would like to make predictions for each row of the csv file.

Comment: You can load chunks of as many rows as you want and then `.apply(predict, axis=1)` to run your predictor on each row.

Answer (score 0):

So I am having the same problem, I can load a csv file a very large one with these commands.

```
    from google.colab import files
    uploaded = files.upload()
    

     //I am using UFO data from nuforc...Its really huge..but thats the 
     name of my csv file.

    import io
    df2 = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(uploaded['nuforc_reports.csv']))
```

The only problem I found is juggling dtypes that happen with large sets of data...still haven't figured mine out yet, I have alot of issues with that right now...but those three commands typically work with google colabs on large sets of data. Go get a cup of coffee because it will process for a minute-