# Best way to use big csv file as lookup to fill data in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a DataFrame with a column that needs to be filled with values from a big csv file.
What would be the best (possibly memory and computation efficient) way to load in the csv file and left-join the data to the DataFrame?

The approaches I have tried/considered:

1. Load in the csv file as a DataFrame and use pandas functions to join: However, this fails with loading in the csv into the memory with a MemoryError.
2. Load in the csv file in a database and use a left join query: I have not tried this one yet, but I hope to avoid a MemoryError.

Comment: I think if need merge only in large data better is some DB, not pandas

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading a huge .csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444679/reading-a-huge-csv-file)

Answer (score 0):

Probably an approach could be using [dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/) and particularly dask [read_csv](https://examples.dask.org/dataframes/01-data-access.html#Tuning-read_csv).

In any case you may consider, as suggested by @jazreal, to store it in an SQL db.