# Reading a big csv file into dataframe

Tags: pandas, csv, parsing, stringio

I have a large csv file (of 13 GB) that I wish to read into a dataframe in Python. So I use:

```
txt = pd.read_csv(r'...file.csv', sep=';', encoding="UTF-8", iterator = True, chunksize=1000)
```

It works just fine, but the data is contained in a **pandas.io.parsers.TextFileReader** type, and I want to have it into a dataframe, in order to manipulate the data.

I manage to get a sample of the data, as a dataframe using:

```
txt.get_chunk(300)
```

But I would like to have all of the data inside a dataframe. So, I tried:

```
for df1 in txt:
df.append(df1)
```

I also tried:

```
df2 = pd.concat([chunk for chunk in txt])
```

Didn't work either.
Can someone please help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you want to have a whole 13 gb file to a single variable dataframe?

Comment: Just get rid of the `chunksize` argument, then `txt` will be a DataFrame. The `chunksize` argument is appropriate when you can't fit everything in memory and instead need to process more manageable parts alone.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a part of data in to a variable using the 'nrows' parameter while reading the file.

`txt = pd.read_csv(r'...file.csv', sep=';', encoding="UTF-8", nrows=1000)`

However, in such cases you have to prefer using the bigger instance to deal with huge data. You can also use multiple instances by setting up dask.

Comment: This is far worse than the `chunksize` option because to get the next 1000 rows you need to re-read the entire file to find your place. The `chunksize` argument is a lot smarter, essentially giving you a generator that you exhaust.

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59730803/best-way-to-use-big-csv-file-as-lookup-to-fill-data-in-dataframe/59731587#59731587), in particular [dask read_csv](https://examples.dask.org/dataframes/01-data-access.html#Tuning-read_csv) could do the trick.