# Python loop over text files and save contents into list of lists, dead kernel

Tags: python, list, loops, kernel, txt

I'm facing a dead kernel problem.
I'm trying to save over 2000 .txt files into a list of lists.
`my_path` contains paths to these 2000+ files. I tried `try` - `except` as below but it didn't help.
The kernel seems to die randomly, i.e. I tried to find files where it breaks, but it seems to break on files which weren't a problem during a previous run.

```
my_list = []
for i in my_path:
    with open(i) as f:
        try:
            lines = f.read().splitlines()
            #print(f)
            my_list.append(lines)
            f.close() 
        except:
            print(f)
```

I also tried opening the files where kernel died separately and they seem to work fine.
I assume something is wrong with my loop?

UPD. I'm using EndeavourOS, Jupyter in VSCode, RAM 16 GB.
I split the paths and it looks like I'm running out of memory. I tried `del ...` and `gc.collect()`, but unsuccessful, it doesn't free the memory and once it's over 12 GB it crashes.

Comment: It would be good if you could add more information to the question, e.g. memory usage, system you're running, etc.

Comment: Okay, then my guess would be that `my_list` just gets too big. What are you trying to do with `my_list`? Maybe a more _lazier_ approach would avoid the problem (like producing the lines through a generator when needed)?

Comment: @Timus thanks a lot, I think you are right, the final while gets way to large which overloads the system. I'm not quite sure what you mean by `producing the lines through a generator when needed`, but after some data inspection I'm just limiting it to the first 1000 lines and it seems to work okay for my sample.

Comment: Sorry for the cryptic language. What I meant is: By using generators you can construct objects which can parse large amounts of data pretty memory-efficiently (_"lazy"_). Whether that option is available here or not depends on what you want to achieve, therefore my question regarding your intentions with `my_list`. If you're interested look [here](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators-uk/GeneratorsUK.pdf) for example (or [here](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators2/index.html?utm_source=pocket_mylist)).

Comment: ... or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444679/reading-a-huge-csv-file) question and the _accepted_ answer. (No guarantee, though, that it is applicable in your use case.)