Reading csv data is faster in R with fread() than in Pandas with read_csv()
I have large datasets- 100 million rows, 100+ columns.
When I read them in R using fread, it gets done quite fast (25 to 30 mins). Same thing takes almost an hour in Python. I had read previously that Pyhon is faster than R but I am seeing the opposite trend.
Sounds like a dumb question but can someone explain why this is?
In Python
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")

In R
library(data.table)
df <- fread("filename.csv")


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444679/reading-a-huge-csv-file

Python is not inherently, or even generally, faster than R. Both languages have many ways of reading a CSV file, with quite a range of speeds. Speed is not just a function of the number of rows but also data type. pandas is particularly slow with strings. data.table is often the fastest way to do something in R. If you want to stick with Python try using a package which may be faster, like polars. Most packages will let you filter which columns to read in, if you don't need them all. Also, do you really need all the rows of the data in memory or could you use something like duckdb?

Agree with @SamR; see e.g.  https://h2oai.github.io/db-benchmark/

If you told us more about the characteristics of your data set (e.g. what types are the 100+ columns? all decimal values (i.e. read as double-precision floating point), or are some character/integer/etc. ?)  Also agree that if you don't have to depend on CSV as the starting point of your pipeline [i.e. you're going to be reading the same data more than once], then there are much more efficient ways to store them (data base, Arrow, parquet, etc.)

vroom::vroom("filename.csv", delim = ",") and arrow::read_csv_arrow("filename.csv") are two options which in my benchmarking can be 2-3x faster than data.table::fread(), but I presume this will vary with different source files.  e.g. using the code here, and also making the data 10x as large: https://gist.github.com/jeroen/723da97422b06d88ce2178ccd947f70b

Likely due (at least in part) to different integer data types
The user eddi's answer to this Stack Overflow question that is very similar to yours suggests that Pandas read_csv() likely uses big integer types (64-bit integers int64) for a lot of the values in each row of data, which takes up a lot more memory than small integer data types. They suggest that fread() is using small-integer data types by default whereas this is something you would have to set with Pandas read_csv().

Interesting, but seems hard to be sure. There are a lot of variables here.

Very true, @BenBolker; integers are just one possible collection of data types, so there could be a lot of other things contributing to the speed difference.
